# Passing array in struct by reference to coder.ceval

Tags: matlab, matlab-coder

I have a struct with very large arrays in it. I use MATLAB coder to generate C code.
In my generated code I wish to call some C function and pass by reference one of the arrays.

For example:

```
coder.ceval('Foo',coder.ref(MyStruct.VeryLargeArray));
```

This is not allowed by MATLAB coder and I get the error:

> coder.ref may only be applied to an expression of the type V or V(E) ...

Since `MyStruct.VeryLargeArray` is very large, as the name suggests, I wish to avoid the abvious solution of copying it to a temporary varliable:

```
UnnecessaryTempVar = MyStruct.VeryLargeArray;
coder.ceval('Foo',coder.ref(UnnecessaryTempVar));
```

Any ideas for a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a C wrapper for `Foo` that accepts a pointer to a struct and forwards the underlying data pointer, `MyStruct->VeryLargeArray`, to `Foo`.

**MATLAB Code `passStruct.m`**:

```
function y = passStruct(x)
%#codegen
coder.cinclude('Foo.h');
s.f = x;
coder.cstructname(s, 'wrapperStruct_T');
y = 10;
y = coder.ceval('WrapFoo', coder.ref(s));
```

**Header file `Foo.h`**:

```
/* Include generated header to get struct definition */
#include "passStruct.h"
double WrapFoo(wrapperStruct_T *s); 
double Foo(double *x);
```

**Source file `Foo.c`**:

```
#include "Foo.h"
double WrapFoo(wrapperStruct_T *s)
{
    return Foo(s->f);
}

double Foo(double *x)
{
    return 2.0*x[0];
}
```

**Codegen command**:

```
codegen passStruct -args zeros(1000) Foo.c -report
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the solution proposed by lilbill39 will work, I came across a different approach:

```
function y = passStruct(x)
%#codegen
s.f = x;
ps = coder.opaque('double *','&s.f[0]');
y = 0;
y = coder.ceval('Foo', ps);
```

However, it assumes that the name of the struct is not changed in the code generation process.